# Python discord bot command with json database

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm making a command that is !command
When you type that in a chat it will update the member(s) score in the database.
The database will look something like this

```
{
  "person": "epikUbuntu"
  "score": "22"
}
```

How would I go on doing that?

edit:
If I wasn't clear I meant ho would I go on doing the python part of it?

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects in python work like dictionaries.

You can write a new dictionary and save it:

```py
data = {"foo": "bar"}

with open("file.json", "w+") as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4) # kwargs for beautification
```

And you can load data from a file (this will be for updating the file):

```py
with open("file.json", "r") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp) # loading json contents into data variable - this will be a dict

data["foo"] = "baz" # updating values
data["bar"] = "foo" # writing new values

with open("file.json", "w+") as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

**Discord.py example:**

```py
import os # for checking the file exists

def add_score(member: discord.Member, amount: int):
    if os.path.isfile("file.json"):
        with open("file.json", "r") as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
        try:
            data[f"{member.id}"]["score"] += amount
        except KeyError: # if the user isn't in the file, do the following
            data[f"{member.id}"] = {"score": amount} # add other things you want to store
    else:
        data = {f"{member.id}": {"score": amount}}
    # saving the file outside of the if statements saves us having to write it twice
    with open("file.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4) # kwargs for beautification
   # you can also return the new/updated score here if you want

def get_score(member: discord.Member):
    with open("file.json", "r") as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
    return data[f"{member.id}"]["score"]

@bot.command()
async def cmd(ctx):
    # some code here
    add_score(ctx.author, 10)
    # 10 is just an example
    # you can use the random module if you want - random.randint(x, y)
    await ctx.send(f"You now have {get_score(ctx.author)} score!")
```

---

**References:**

- [Context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)
- [Dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
- [Loading data from a json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)
- [Writing to a json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)

Comment: it would be really good if you could include discord.py examples.

Comment: @epiKubuntu Sorry for the late reply! I added in a small example ^